# Ubuntu 16.04 network issue

Tags: networking, 16.04, virtualbox, network-bridge

I have Ubuntu 16.04 as main OS in my laptop.

My laptop is connected for wifi. When i create new vm in virtualbox using

```
Network:
Attached to: Bridge Adapter
Name: wlp9s0
```

My VM is not connecting to internet.

My host (laptop) as internet working successfully.

**VM Settings:**

[image]

**VM**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should select "cable connected" option